# Remove character from column based on condition on another column in Redshift sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table where I want to do the following:
If col_1 has values "sakc" or "cosc", remove occurrences of character "_" from those rows of col_2.

Example:

Given table_1

```
col_1            col_2

sakc             abc_aw
sakc             asw_12
cosc             absd12
dasd             qwe_32
cosc             dasd_1
```

Desired table_1

```
col_1            col_2

sakc             abcaw
sakc             asw12
cosc             absd12
dasd             qwe_32
cosc             dasd1
```

I tried using something along the lines of:

```
select case when col_1 in ('sakc', 'cosc') then trim("_" from col_2) end col_2 from table_1;
```

But I am sure it's not the right way and is giving me errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replace()`

```
SELECT  
  col_1
 ,CASE 
    WHEN col_1 in ('sakc', 'cosc') THEN REPLACE(col_2, '_', '')
    ELSE col_2 
  END col2 
FROM table_1;
```

Comment: Yeah, this works! when you added the 'else' part. Thanks!

Comment: @Gompu Yes, sorry I caught it slightly after I originally answered.